# ngTagsInput with filtered auto-complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a tags input-field, with auto-complete. Here is the Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
               $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
               return $http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data'));
                }
            });
```

HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true" display-property="categoryname" placeholder="Add a Tag">
            <auto-complete max-results-to-show="4" min-length="0" source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
        </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
    </body>
```

The `$http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data'));` returns `tags.json` :

```
[{"categoryname":"wifi"},{"categoryname":"cable"},{"categoryname":"tv"},{"categoryname":"geyser"},{"categoryname":"fridge"},{"categoryname":"sofa"},{"categoryname":"lift"},{"categoryname":"gas stove"},{"categoryname":"washing machine"}]
```

This works perfeclty. When I enter some input in the field, the suggestions appear in the dropdown.

**Problem**: Now I want the suggestions being displayed to be filtered, based on user input.

For that I changed my Angular code to this:

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, tags) {

          $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
            return tags.load();
          };
    });

    app.service('tags', function($q, $http, $filter) {
    var tags = $http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data'));

    this.load = function(query) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve( $filter('filter')($scope.tags, query));
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  });
```

Doesn't work :(

Any and all help is appreciated.

Here is the console:
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors?
Because i see that nowhere you have injected `$filter` service into `tags` service.

Comment: @Tarun Thanks for the feedback, I've made the edit. Still doesn't work

Comment: What is `$scope` on this line
```javascript
      deferred.resolve( $filter('filter')($scope.tags, query));
```

Comment: it is the response `[{"categoryname":"wifi"},{"categoryname":"cable"},{"categoryname":"tv"},{"categoryname":"geyser"},{"categoryname":"fridge"},{"categoryname":"sofa"},{"categoryname":"lift"},{"categoryname":"gas stove"},{"categoryname":"washing machine"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the service to something like:

```
app.service('tags', function($q, $http, $filter) {
    this.load = function(query) {
        return $http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data')).then(
             function(result) {
                 return $filter('filter')(result.data, query)
             }
        )
    };
});
```

The service now return a chained promises and the resolve function is dealing with the filter.

You can cache the results, and return a promise (Using the `$q` service) that relove the array of tags previously returned from the server.

Don't know if the filter itself is working - But now it will have list of items to filter and not `undefined` value (`$scope.tags`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now the service works, however the filter isn't working

Comment: I have to go, but i'll have a second look at the filter issue when i'm back in a few hours

Comment: Hey, I made some changes in `$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
            return tags.load();
          };` . Just had to pass `query` as a parameter inside `tags.load()` . Works fine now. Thanks a million!